# Wrong PHP version shown at phpinfo for Azure Web App

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, php-7.1, azureportal

When changing the PHP version from 5.6 to 7.1 on my Azure Web App from the Azure Portal will succeed. But when I run phpinfo() from an php-file, it is still showing me the old version 5.6.31 of PHP.. Also my code that I uploaded to the Azure Web App doesn't understand the 7.1 changes..

I already updated the PHP version from the Azure CLI and restarted the server. But no luck :( Does anyone else have another option to try?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this behavior, but there are few options you could try.

***Option 1:***

Add a line to the **Handler Mappings** with the following values:

*Extension*: `*.php`

*Processor path*: `D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\php-cgi.exe`

[image]

***Option 2:***

Create a `web.config` file and put it into the root folder of your website.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="FastCGIHandler" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v7.1\php-cgi.exe" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

---

All pre-installed PHP runtimes could be find in `D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP` (x86) and `D:\Program Files\PHP` (x64).

[image]

Comment: Your'e right! In the web.config file i had php 5.6... Changed it to 7.1 and i works!